# Marginal pdf with nonnegative random variables

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function, bivariate-distributions, marginal-distribution

Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two nonnegative random variables that satisfy

$$P(X_1 > x_1,  X_2 > x_2) = \exp \left[−\mu x_1 − \nu x_2 − \lambda \max(x_1, x_2)\right] ,\text{ for }x_1 \ge 0 \text{ and }x_2 \ge 0\,,$$

where $\mu, \nu$, and $\lambda$ are positive parameters.

Find the marginal p.d.f.s of $X_1$ respectively.

(My Answer)

1. x1≥x2 ,  max(x1,x2)=x1
   $$ f(x_1) = \int_0^\infty exp(−µx_1 − νx_2 − λ max(x_1, x_2) dx_2 $$
   $$ = \int_0^\infty exp(−µx_1 − νx_2 − λ x_1) dx_2 $$
   $$ =exp(−µx_1− λ x_1)\int_0^\infty exp(− νx_2 ) dx_2 $$
   $$ =exp(−µx_1− λ x_1) (-\frac{1}{v})exp(− νx_2 )|_0^\infty$$
   $$ = \frac{exp(-(µ+λ)x_1)}{v}$$
2. x1<x2 ,  max(x1,x2)=x2
   In the same way as x1≥x2,
   $$ f(x_2) = \int_0^\infty exp(−µx_1 − νx_2 − λ max(x_1, x_2) dx_2 $$
   $$ = \int_0^\infty exp(−µx_1 − νx_2 − λ x_2) dx_2 $$
   $$ =exp(-µx_1)\int_0^\infty exp(− νx_2 − λ x_2) dx_2 $$
   $$ =exp(-µx_1) (−\frac{1}{ν+λ})exp(-(ν+λ)x_2)|_0^\infty$$
   $$ = \frac{exp(-µx_1)}{ν+λ}$$

Is it right?

Comment: It is not right. $ exp [−µx1 − νx2 − λ max(x1, x2)]$ is not the joint density. You have to differentiate this w.r.t $x_1$ and $x_2$ to get the density function.

Comment: Please format your posts properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just out $x_2=0$ to get $P(X_1>x_1)=e^{-(\lambda+\mu)x_1}$ for $x_1 \geq 0$. Hence the marginal density of $X_1$ is $(\lambda+\mu) e^{-(\lambda+\mu)x_1}$ for $x_1 \geq 0$. Similarly write down the density of $X_2$.

Comment: Isn't it   exp(−(λ+μ)x1) / (λ+μ)   if   exp(-(λ+μ)x1)  is integrated from  x1  to  infty ?

Comment: No integration is involved. Density is the **derivative** of the distribution function. @user913386

Comment: Thanks!! The value I've differentiated is  -(λ+μ)exp(−(λ+μ)x1). Is minus(-) an erasure?

Comment: @user913386 Density is the derivativeof $P(X \leq x)$. If you differentiate $P(X>x)$ which is $1-P(X \leq x)$ you get $-1$ times the density.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @user913386 If you are satisfied with an aswer you can consider clicking the check mark to the left of the answer to approve it. Otherwise the question will be listed as an unanswered question.